# How to stop generating Photoshop image asset for the whole image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have the image FishingBoat.psd and it has three layers (Fisherman.svg, FishingLine.svg and FishingLineStroke.svg) that I would like to generate image assets from. But Photoshop keeps generating fourth (unwanted) asset FishingBoat.svg (with all the layers combined). Can I somehow stop it from this behaviour and generate just three assets?

Comment: You sure you don't have a layer named `FishingBoat.svg` in the document? Sounds like it would be a group that is named that.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. There is nothing above these three layers.

Answer (score 0):

In lack of better solution I just dragged all the layers to the new image and now it works correctly. Maybe some bug?

Answer (score -2):

You can rasterize those layers first, and hide the svg file to prevent regenerating new pixels.

Comment: I don't understand. These are shape layers, I don't want them rasterized.